# Android ListView for showing lyrics

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-custom-view

I am trying to make a `ListView` for showing lyrics. I have very little experience with making custom compound views. So I would like to know what my approach should be to make this view. The `ListView` must have these features

- auto-scrolling based on the song (the timing information will be stored in the list adapter)
- highlighting the current line which is being played on the audio
- indentation on some lines to make it look more like a nicely formatted poem
- users should not be able to scroll the list when the song is playing (i.e. the list is being auto-scrolled) but it should be scrollable when the song is paused

I don't know if the view should extend list view or not. If not then what should it extend and what should be my approach?

Comment: What have you tried? How do you visualize the `view` working? Do you have a sketch?

Comment: I am not sure a ListView is what you want here, although it can be done. Not everything that scrolls down should be a ListView, sometimes a ScrollView with some TextViews inside it is enough. If you want the user to not be able to scroll at all I think that what you need might not even be a ScrollView, but some form of a custom view where you do the drawing yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly, I really don't have enough information to answer this completely, but this is what I would do:

If it were up to me, since you don't want a scroll capability at all (you want to make it appear as if it is scrolling, not to actually allow the user to scroll), I would not use any of the complex views like ListView or ScrollView, I would just write a custom view, simply extending View. I would override it's onDraw() method and use Canvas.drawText(...) to draw the words, having two different Paints, one for the current word and another for all other words. As for the "scrolling" effect, you can keep a number that represents the current top line that you can see, and add one to this number when you want to scroll to the next line. However to make it smooth you can manipulate where exactly you start drawing the texts and move it slowly upwards, so that it would appear that everything is scrolling down.

** Maybe it would be better to use SurfaceView here instead of just View, especially if you want a background image and smooth blending and better a look, since SurfaceView is much better for complex drawings **

If that is too complicated for you and you want to use existing views entirely without doing any of the drawing yourself, I would recommend a vertical ScrollView, you fill the ScrollView with horizontal LinearLayouts for each line, and each of those is filled with TextViews for every specific word. You can programatically build the TextViews and the LinearLayouts. Use ScrollView's scrollTo(...) or SmoothScrollTo(...) to scroll to the right location. You can prevent the user from scrolling by capturing all the motion events before they are used to scroll.

Both approaches will of course require you to maintain some form of data structure to hold the times each word is selected.